# Javascript for() not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a progress bar with Javascript. I am using a for loop to run the code:

```
var prog = document.getElementById("progressbar").max;
var progg = document.getElementById("progressbar");

function runAnimation(){            
    for(var i=0; i < prog; i++){
        var hit = progg.value;
        hit++;
    }
};
```

This should make the value of the progressbar increment each time the function runs, but it doesn't work. I am not getting any errors in the console. How can I make the progressbar's value rise incrementally?

Comment: is  max custom attribute of element progressbar?

Comment: No, it's standard in html5!
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp

Comment: Why would *reading* from the property *alter* the `value` of the progress bar? The `hit++` statement operates on the *variable* hit (it is about the same as `hit = hit + 1`) and has *no effect* upon the progress bar or the `value` property it has. After fixing that, you'll only want to set the progress *one* time per animation/timeout callback (eg. every 100 milliseconds) as multiple changes within a single callback will not be reflected in the UI..

Comment: Try to think about your problem yourself before you ask a question here.  Its clear from your code sample that you are not even attempting to change the progress bar's current value, so of course it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

For an "animated" effect, you can recursively call a `setTimeout`, based on the current `value` and `max` value of your progress bar. Something like:

```
var progg = document.getElementById("progressbar");
function runAnimation(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (progg.value <= progg.max) {
            progg.value++;
            runAnimation();   
        }
    }, 10);
};

runAnimation();
```

Changing your `timeout` value (`10` in the above example) will increase/decrease the progress bar.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cL7nygsr/

For a more interesting use of `setTimeout` (since the above is just basically `setInterval`), call it after an operation has completed before calling your next iteration. Here's an updated fiddle which includes a random update of the progress bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/cL7nygsr/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var b = document.getElementById('progress').max;
window.setInterval(a,1000);
function a() {
  document.getElementById('progress').value++;
  if (document.getElementById('progress').value >= b) {
    window.clearInterval(a);
  }
}
```

Here is code to increment progress bar value every 1 second, you can change to 2 second by replacing 1000 with 2000.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with your `hit` variable once you increment it. You want to do this instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < prog; i++) {
    progg.value++;
}
```

Comment: This  makes it race forward, you can't even see the progress bar moving. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Settimeout doesn't pause things. It allows you to asynchronously make a call at a later time. This code does nothing other than loop just as fast.

Comment: Crap, you're right. Sorry, I was in a SQL and C# mindset right now.